# Strtotime not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

My goal is to compare the current time with the last visited time and if was 5 minutes ago then allow to visit again, else, deny! Here what I have so far

```
$last_activate = strtotime($last_activ); //$last_activ is TIMESTAMP value retrieved from MySQL database
$current_time = strtotime('now');

if(($current_time - $last_activate) > strtotime('5 minutes')){
    //allow access
}
else{
     //deny access
}
```

At the moment, the code above always executes `else` statement even if `$last_activate` was 24 hours ago. Anyone knows what point I am missing?

Comment: What's the value of `$last_activ` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtotime('5 minutes')` means `now + 5 minutes`. Proof:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('5 minutes'));
2013-03-21 19:41:27
```

Do this instead:

```
if(($current_time - $last_activate) > 5 * 60){
```

Comment: Thank you! However, could you please explain me why my previous attempt was always 'deny'? Didn't really understand how strtotime converts the date etc.

Comment: @PanayiotisNicolaou The time difference returned the number of seconds between the events. 120 for instance. While `strtotime(5 minutes)` returns the timestamp 5 minutes from now, `1363917098` is now's value. You see that it is always bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `5 minutes` with `5 minutes ago`.